# Rename all files(from different folders) in one buffer?

Tags: dired

In folder I have 5 subfolders:

```
drawable-hdpi\
drawable-mdpi\
drawable-xhdpi\
drawable-xxhdpi\
drawable-xxxhdpi\
```

In all of this 5 subfolders I have files with same names:

```
ic_m_brands_gray.png
ic_m_brands_orange.png
ic_m_favourites_gray.png
ic_m_favourites_orange.png
ic_m_home_gray.png
```

I need to rename all of this files in ALL (five) subfolders.

So I do this by **dired mode** and package **iedit**

My steps:

1. Go to folder **drawable-hdpi**
2. `C-x C-q` toogle edit mode
3. Go to file with same suffix (**gray**)
4. Select region then *iedit-mode*
5. Rename to desire suffix
6. Press `C-c C-c`
7. Repeat steps *1-6* for another 4 subfolders.

Here example:

[image: step1]

[image: step2]

[image: step3]

OK. It's work. Fine.

But I think it's to slow (too many steps).

Is it possible to show **ALL** files (from 5 subfolders) in **ONE** buffer? And then in this ONE buffer rename all files?

It's will be a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dired-maybe-insert-subdir` (by default bound to `i` in Dired), on each folder, before using steps 2-5 in your question. See [Subdirectories in Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Subdirectories-in-Dired.html) in the manual.

I myself use `dired-subtree` from MELPA (it is a part of [Dired Hacks](https://github.com/Fuco1/dired-hacks) by Fuco1). You can then use `dired-subtree-toggle`, which I think is a nicer interface.

Comment: Yes!!! Emacs is COOL!!!